# Deleted UIScrollView still showing in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I was using a UIScrollView in an Xcode project, but decided to go to a UITableView instead. I deleted the UIScrollView but it still show up when I'm testing the app.

I have tried all suggestions I have found here: cleaning, clearing the cache, deleting the app from the device, deleting derived data and deleting the contents of ~/var/folders. All to no avail.

Anyone have any ideas of where I'm going wrong?  I'd really rather not start again from the start.

Thanks.

Comment: If you´re using storyboards, you can browse the source code by right clicking the file in the left menu -> Open As -> Source Code. You might find a clue there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, didn't know I could do that. I think when I deleted the view I clicked delete reference rather than move to trash. I think that's where the problem has come from. But don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: So it was a UIScrollV subclass? You can delete the files manually from the project folder in Finder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you deleted the UIScrollView from your storyboard/xib which ever you used if you taken into it.

And also make sure you didn't add UIScrollView anywhere from your code.